# Create a custom prefix on a UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid, rails-migrations

I would like to know if there is any way to create a custom prefix on UUID's in rails. I would like to generate something like:

```
"ret_a44691c8-93e2-11e8-ac1c-1b3aa40a1cae"
```

I found this code, which I can add to my migration to create the UUID:

```
t.uuid "uuid", default: "uuid_generate_v4()"
```

But this would generate something like:

```
"a44691c8-93e2-11e8-ac1c-1b3aa40a1cae"
```

Is it possible to get the format that I want?

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: I am using a Postgres DB (version 10)

Comment: postgres defines a UUID as `as a sequence of lower-case hexadecimal digits, in several groups separated by hyphens, specifically a group of 8 digits followed by three groups of 4 digits followed by a group of 12 digits, for a total of 32 digits representing the 128 bits` => https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html

Comment: why do you even need to prepend `ret_` ?

Comment: I wanted to define customer and retailer uuid's with a prefix. I suppose it may be easier to just add it on as part of the page and keep the uuid as it should be as per your previous comment.

Comment: All generated UUID's are universally unique, there's no need to prefix them. If you want to identify the customer and retailer then create a separate column for that.

Comment: yeah, that's what I assumed, I thought I would ask and see if anyone else had done this. I will just keep to my original plan then.

Comment: Cool thanks Leo, I am tempted to stay safe as Ashish has discussed. Keep it standard.

Comment: @Leo That'll throw an error in Postgres => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f429/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, postgres defines the UUID as (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html)

```
A sequence of lower-case hexadecimal digits, in several groups separated by 
hyphens, specifically a group of 8 digits followed by three groups of 4 digits 
followed by a group of 12 digits, for a total of 32 digits representing the 128 bits
```

So you can't prefix `ret_` in UUID column. Also you shouldn't, if you want to identify retailer and customer create another column for it.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f429/2) when concatenated UUID is used. It'll throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prefix your UUIDs, you can do something like this in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  uuid TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT concat('ret-', uuid_generate_v4())
);
```

This will generate a uuid like:

```
'ret-a44691c8-93e2-11e8-ac1c-1b3aa40a1cae'
```

Comment: What would be better for indexing purposes is to store the column as BYTEA using `convert_to(,)`.